# Javascript - how to identify the pattern using RegExp

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The submit button should popup an alert message saying that the pattern on postcode and zipcode are wrong when user input it wrong. But I can't seem to make it work. I don't want to use the "pattern=" in form. I want to display an alert box. And I need to use the RegExp method. Any ideas why?

This is my code:

```
                <script>
                function validation(){
                  var icn = document.getElementById("icno").value;
                  var postcode = document.getElementById("pstcode").value;
                  var regexp = new RegExp(icn,"\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}");
          var regexp1 = new RegExp(postcode,"[0-9]{5}");

                  if (regexp.exec(icn)){
            return true;
                  }
                  else{
            alert("Please enter your IC correctly")
                  }

          if (regexp1.exec(postcode)){
            return true;
                  }
                  else{
            alert("Please enter your postcode correctly")
                  }
                }
                </script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: but there's should be dashes in the pattern. @smerny

Comment: `var regexp = /\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}/;
          var regexp1 = /[0-9]{5}/;` - and add `^` / `$` anchors if you need a full string match.

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/copk8mbg/) - is it working as expected?

Comment: Oh! Okay! Now I get it! Thanks a lot! You rock! <3

Comment: I will post that then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  But the postcode isnt working... I didn't noticed that.. Is it my if-else is wrong? The postcode should be in 5 numbers only.

Comment: Replace `exec` with `test`

Comment: Why don't you test like `if (regexp1.test(postcode))` much more sensible.

Comment: @Redu I've tried it but still wont work for the postcode. Is it my if-else is wrong?

Comment: You are using the RegExp constructor wrong. Actually you don't need to use a RegExp constructor if your regex input is not dynamic (i.e. coming within a varibale) just make it like `var regexp = /\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}/, regexp1 = /\d{5}/;`

Comment: @Redu  Oh! Okay! Thanks for the info! Now I understand it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the RegExp, you can pass 2 arguments: 1) the pattern, 2) the flag(s). You passed the variable containing text to search as the first  argument, and pattern as the second one.

The second issue is that you expect a full string match, so, you missed the anchors (`^` - start of string -  and `$` - end of string).

```
var regexp = /^\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
var regexp1 = /^\d{5}$/;
```

And then correct the `if` blocks:

```
var icn_check = regexp.test(icn);
var pcode_check = regexp1.test(postcode);

if (icn_check && pcode_check){      // Only return true if both fields are valid
   return true;
}
else {
  if (!pcode_check) {                                // If post code is invalid
    alert("Please enter your postcode correctly");
  }
  if (!icn_check) {                                  // If ICN is invalid
    alert("Please enter your IC correctly");
  }
}
```

And use `RegExp#test()` instead of `exec()` to check if a string matches a regex.

See [the JS fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/copk8mbg/2/)

```js
function validation() {
  var icn = document.getElementById("icno").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("pstcode").value;
  var regexp = /^\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
  var regexp1 = /^\d{5}$/;
  var icn_check = regexp.test(icn);
  var pcode_check = regexp1.test(postcode);
  if (icn_check && pcode_check) {
    return true;
  } else {
    if (!pcode_check) {
      alert("Please enter your postcode correctly");
    }
    if (!icn_check) {
      alert("Please enter your IC correctly");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="validation()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Regular Expression</legend>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" size="30" placeholder="Enter name.">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="icno">IC No</label>
    <input type="text" id="icno" size="15" placeholder="E.g. 889601-11-6575">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="address">Address 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" size="30" placeholder="Address 1">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="address">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" size="30" placeholder="Address 2">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" id="pstcode" size="8" placeholder="E.g 21030">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please check the updated demo - the alerts show up if you do not provide valid input.

Comment: but still, var regexp1 didn't work. I've tried to change it to [0-9]{5} also cant work it out. It is supposed to be the same as regexp but why it won't test it? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: You mean, if the first ICN is valid, then the input is accepted, right? I updated the code.

Comment: It works perfectly! But why my if-else just now is wrong? Can you explain more about this? :)

Comment: Your original code logic for if-else is wrong because you return true after checking ICN code, and the postcode does not have to be valid in that case as it is not checked at all. I suggest checking if *both* are valid first, then, check which check failed and show appropriate messages then.

Comment: Okay! I got it now! You're really great! Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `RegExp` and `.exec`, try this:

```js
function validation() {
  var icn = document.getElementById("icno").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("pstcode").value;
  var regexp = new RegExp(/\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}/);
  var regexp1 = new RegExp(/[0-9]{5}/);

  if (regexp.exec(icn) !== null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter your IC correctly")
  }

  if (regexp1.exec(postcode) !== null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter your postcode correctly")
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="validation()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Regular Expression</legend>

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" size="30" placeholder="Enter name.">
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="icno">IC No</label>
    <input type="text" id="icno" size="15" placeholder="E.g. 889601-11-6575">
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="address">Address 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" size="30" placeholder="Address 1">
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="address">Address 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" size="30" placeholder="Address 2">
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" id="pstcode" size="8" placeholder="E.g 21030">
    </br>
    </br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

But I recommend you to use `.test`, it's simple:

```
function validation() {
   var icn = document.getElementById("icno").value;
   var postcode = document.getElementById("pstcode").value;

   if (/\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}/.test(icn)) {
     return true;
   } else {
     alert("Please enter your IC correctly")
   }

   if (/[0-9]{5}/.test(postcode)) {
     return true;
   } else {
     alert("Please enter your postcode correctly")
   }
 }
```

Comment: The icn method is working perfectly, thanks but the postcode isnt... I've tried both of your codings but the postcode isn't working. :)

Comment: The patterns used here do not validate the input as full strings and allow partial matches. The if-else logic will fail if ICN is correct and postcode is not.

Comment: What result are you expecting?? For me is working if you want 5 characters long and the first character a digit 0 to 9.